# Need help in row operations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

My dataframe looks like this :

```
    SNP     A   B   S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7
0   rs123   T   C   001 100 100 100 001 100 100
2   rs126   G   A   010 100 010 100 010 100 010
```

I want the output as :

```
    SNP     A   B   S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7
0   rs123   T   C   CC  TT  TT  TT  CC  TT  TT
2   rs126   G   A   GA  GG  GA  GG  GA  GG  GA
```

The condition is

```
if '001' --> df['B'] + df['B']
if '010' --> df['A'] + df['B']
if '100' --> df['A'] + df['A']
```

My Code

```
for col in df.iloc[:,3:].columns:    
   df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))

    def myfunc(x):
        if x == '001':
            return df['B'] + df['B']
        elif x == '010':
            return df['A'] + df['B']
        elif x == '100':
            return df['A'] + df['A']
```

But I am not getting desired output :( Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Absolutely!! Just did. Thanks alot bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add three summations as new columns to the dataframe:

```
df["B+B"] = df["B"] + df["B"]
df["A+B"] = df["A"] + df["B"]
df["A+A"] = df["A"] + df["A"]
```

Iterate over the columns and apply the logic like below:

```
for i in range(1, 8):
    df[f"S{i}"][df[f"S{i}"] == "001"] = df["B+B"][df[f"S{i}"] == "001"]
    df[f"S{i}"][df[f"S{i}"] == "010"] = df["A+B"][df[f"S{i}"] == "010"]
    df[f"S{i}"][df[f"S{i}"] == "100"] = df["A+A"][df[f"S{i}"] == "100"]
df.drop(["B+B", "A+B", "A+A"], axis=1)


    SNP     A   B   S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7
0   rs123   T   C   CC  TT  TT  TT  CC  TT  TT
1   rs126   G   A   GA  GG  GA  GG  GA  GG  GA
```